# How to publish Blazor-Wasm Hosted to local IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor-webassembly

I have been happily deploying my site to a web-host without issue.

I am now looking to make a local deployment to my dev machine's IIS.

My publish profile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>true</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>C:\CosmosLocalIIS</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>REDACTED</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I am told that my publish is successful and I can see the deployment files in C:\CosmosLocalIIS.

I have used IIS Manager to configure the site:

### Site Basic Settings

[image: Site Basic Settings]

If I click "Test Settings ..." I get this result:

### Test Settings Results

[image: Test Settings Results]

It suggests giving 'Read' access to the ApplicationPoolId, but am not sure how to go about this and not sure if this is the source of my problem.

### Site Advanced Settings

[image]

My list of bindings is as follows:

### Bindings

[image: Bindings]
[image: http Bindings]
[image: https Bindings]

I had therefore expected that when browsing to cosmosiis.com, I would get my site.  But I get a Chrome "The site can't be reached" error.

Have I missed a step or any suggestions on how I might debug this?

Comment: IIS service will only have permissions under the www root folder, either move the files to wwwroot or grant IIS permissions to the specified path

Comment: "I had therefore expected that when browsing to cosmosiis.com, I would get my site." Why? DNS settings are missing, so browsers won't be able to reach your IIS server at all and report errors like "The site can't be reached" as expected.

Comment: @fuzzybear - I seem to have got it working without changing any security on the C:\CosmosLocalIIS folder.  Currently only has `Authenticated Users`, `SYSTEM`, `Administrators` and `Users`.  I didn't add 'IIS_IUSRS'.  Perhaps I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @LexLi I was browsing from my local machine to IIS on local machine, so hadn't appreciated the relevance of DNS.  However, this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis/ brought my attention to the 'hosts' file.  Adding a record `127.0.0.1  cosmosiis.com` to this file solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Hacking hosts file is still part of the DNS configuration (as you override records from your DNS servers), which now you know very well. You can post and accept your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Further to pointers from *Lex Li*, the answer when accessing local IIS from local browser is to put a short-circuit DNS record in the **hosts** file found at:

> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Adding a line:

```
127.0.0.1  cosmosiis.com
```

solved the problem.